# Sumar posiciones de un string en una lista PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Necesito sumar las posiciones de un string en una lista. Mi función tiene como parámetro una lista con strings y devolver una lista con las posiciones. Por ejemplo: `suma_lista(['00101', '00111', '00010'])` y esto me debería devolver `[0,0,2,2,2]`. No puedo pasar los numeros a enteros ya que los ceros de delante desaparecen y necesito que aparezcan en el resultado.
Yo he pensado el siguiente código pero no me devuelve lo que quiero y no encuentro el error.

```
def suma_lista(lista):
    suma = 0
    suma_total = []
    for j in range(0, len(lista)):
        print('Posicion j:', j)
        for i in range(0, len(lista)):
            print('Posicion i:', i)
            #print(lista[i][j])
            suma = suma + int(lista[i][j])
            print('Esta es la suma', suma)
        suma_total.append(suma)
return suma_total
```

Lo que he pensado es ir recorriendo la lista y a su vez las posiciones del string. Seguramente haya una forma más fácil pero se me ha ocurrido esta. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pesar de que la respuesta de Alberto ha sido magnífica, creo que es oportuno añadir esta respuesta también en vista de que tu problema se presta de manera ideal para aplicar la función¹ builtin `zip()`.

Esta función lo que hace es, dado uno o más iterables de entrada, devolver un nuevo iterable (objeto de tipo `zip`) que contiene los elementos devueltos en cada iteración de cada iterable de entrada, agrupados en tuplas.

De esta manera, si tenemos una lista `numeros = [1, 2, 3]` y otra lista `letras = ['a', 'b', 'c']`, entonces al aplicar `zip(numeros, letras)`, tendremos *(después de iterar sobre el objeto `zip` devuelto)* lo siguiente:

```
(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')
```

Por lo tanto, podemos extrapolar esto mismo a tu problema, [desempaquetando](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) las strings contenidas dentro de `lista`, como iterables de entrada a la función `zip()`.

Posteriormente, podemos usar una [comprehensión de lista](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) para generar la salida que queremos. Dentro de esta comprehensión, podemos usar luego otras builtins functions (`sum` y `map`) que nos ayuden con nuestro fin.

El código se leería de la siguiente forma:

```py
def sumar_valores_por_cada_posicion(lista):
    elementos_agrupados_por_posicion = zip(*lista)
    return [
        sumar_valores_de(elementos_en_una_posicion_dada)
        for elementos_en_una_posicion_dada in elementos_agrupados_por_posicion
    ]


def sumar_valores_de(elementos_en_una_posicion_dada):
    return sum(map(int, elementos_en_una_posicion_dada))
```

El cual puede ser usado de la siguiente manera:

```
sumar_valores_por_cada_posicion(['00101', '00111', '00010'])
# El valor retornado será: [0, 0, 2, 2, 2]
```

---

¹ *En realidad `zip` no es una función, sino una clase. Al llamarla lo que estamos haciendo es crear instancias de tipo `zip`. Sin embargo, es bastante común referirse a ella como una función y por esta razón lo hice también acá.*

Answer (score 4):

Tu problema se puede resolver de varias formas, yo en vez de usar dos bucles `for` usaría un `while` con un contador, el código quedaría así:

```
numeros = ['00101', 
           '00111',
           '00010']

def suma_lista(lista, tamano_numero):
    contador = 0
    suma_realizada = []
    while contador < tamano_numero:
        suma_realizada.append(sum([int(num[contador]) for num in lista]))
        contador +=1
    return suma_realizada


suma_lista(numeros, 5)
```

**Salida:** `[0, 0, 2, 2, 2]`

### Explicación código

Lo que hacemos es que se va iterando por la posición de cada caracter del número, para ello lo que hago es:

- Inicializo dos variables una `contador` que romperá el bucle `while` cuando alcance el tamaño de un número (en este caso los números son de longitud 5) y me **servirá como indice** para acceder al elemento que necesito en cada lista. La otra variable es la lista donde se irán agregando los números sumados `suma_realizada`
- Inicio el bucle `while` que se rompera, cuando se llegue a la longitud máxima del bucle `tamano_numero`
- Dentro del `while` utilizo [List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) para recorrer cada string que se encuentra en `numeros` y devolver las posiciones que estoy buscando con `contador` en cada string `[int(num[contador]) for num in lista]`.
- Por último sumo la iteración de ese bucle `for` y agrego la suma, a la variable `suma_realizada` que será la que se retornará cuando se rompa el bucle `while`

### Utilizando tu código

Casí lo tenías, te faltan dos pequeñas cosas, que creo que puedes averiguar viendo mi código directamente

```
numeros = ['00101', 
           '00111',
           '00010']

def suma_lista(lista):
    suma = 0
    suma_total = []
    for j in range(len(lista[0])):
        print('Posicion j:', j)
        for i in range(len(lista)):
            print('Posicion i:', i)
            #print(lista[i][j])
            suma += int(lista[i][j])
            print('Esta es la suma', suma)
        suma_total.append(suma)
        suma = 0
    return suma_total


suma_lista(numeros)
```

Errores:

- En el primer `for` tienes que poner la longitud, no de la lista, si no de los strings. Lo que te sucedía era que al poner la longitud de la lista, se paraba en la tercera iteración, ya que la lista tiene 3 elementos.
- `suma=0` En el segundo bucle `for` tienes que convertir la variable `suma` a cero, ya que si no acumularías la suma.

### Bonus

- Si quieres empezar tu función `range` por el cero, no es necesario ponerlo
- `suma += int(lista[i][j])` es igual que `suma = suma + int(lista[i][j])` y se puede utilizar con otros operadores como resta, multiplicación, división, etc.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, la verdad que si, casi lo tenía... gracias por el nivel de detalle! He entendido todo.

Comment: De nada siempre es un gusto ayudar :) Si te ha servido mi respuesta, la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es aceptando la respuesta en el tick  "aceptar respuesta",  y ¿Por qué no? ¡Darle también un voto positivo! Esto no solo me recomenpensara a mí por la ayuda, si no que hará que la pregunta perdure en el tiempo y le pueda ser de ayuda a personas con el mismo problema que tú en el futuro! Te recomiendo leer [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/vota-pronto-vota-con-frecuencia)

Answer (score 2):

Mi solución:

```
suma = [sum([int(numeros[i][j]) for i in range(len(numeros))]) for j in range(len(numeros[0]))]
```

La expresión mas interna es

```
[int(numeros[i][j]) for i in range(len(numeros))]
```

que produce una lista de tres dígitos, cada uno extraído desde la misma posición en cada numero:

```
[0, 0, 0] para j = 0
[0, 0, 0] para j = 1
[1, 1, 0] para j = 2
[0, 1, 1] para j = 3
[1, 1, 0] para j = 4
```

Cada lista se suma con `sum`, obteniendo un elemento del contador, los que se agregan en una lista final:

```
[0, 0, 2, 2, 2]
```